# react router v6, match params id not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi I have a main page called FeaturedProduct.js which lists all the products fetch from the API https://fakestoreapi.com.

I trying to set up react router dom version (6) whereby user click on any of the product will open up that single product through Product.js but the error - No routes matched location "/products/6".

This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-smoke-r7yik9?file=/src/App.js

The FeaturedProduct.js work ok

// I try to key in the url manually into the browser i.e. localhost:8888/products/1 but it is blank too

Comment: The first issue is that your route is configured as `/product/:id` (without the s)

Comment: Your second issue is going to be that, inside of `<Product />` you're using `match` as a prop but I _don't think_ that's how it works. I believe you're want to use the `useParams` hook... something like `const { id } = useParams()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `useParams()` hook to de-structure your `id` variable from the url. The `useParams()` hook is provided by the react-router package by default. You can read more about it - [Here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params)

Meanwhile, I've also edited your code and implemented the `useParams()` hook. You can check it out [in this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-chatterjee-p7m1y8?file=%2Fsrc%2FProduct.js%3A0-1330)

If you've got any other questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: thanks!  But how do you console.log to see all the properties of the product that we click? because when I clicked on the product view - it doesn't reflect 1 product

Comment: Fix the routes in your sandbox so the detail page matches and renders.

Comment: It's simple. You're using the wrong URL to query the products. Navigate to the [docs](https://fakestoreapi.com/docs) and you'll see that in order to get one product, you need to pass the id like this :- `https://www.fakestoreapi.com/products/id`

Right now, you're doing it like this :- `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/?id=${id}`
Just remove the `?id=` part and you'll be good to go.

Comment: but ${id} is not an array so it will have issue with the map function right

Comment: yes, i know. I think you will be able to figure that our by yourself. If not then hit me up. I will help you along with it.